# Change EEVEE volumetric sampling limits

Tags: python, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics, artifacts

I'm trying to minimize artifacts in EEVEE and I want to change EEVEE volumetric sample and shadow sample limits beyond the cap, is there a Python solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a Python solution for this.  The cap is set in C code in `rna_scene.c` at line [7066](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_scene.c#L7066) and is enforced in C code.  You would have to recompile Blender to change the value.